# How to split data to rows and columns in C#

Tags: c#

My program works with two Dictionary<string, double>, edge case is when only one dictionary is present

Format of each dictionary is shown below:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| a-b | 0 |
| a-c | 1 |
| a-d | 2 |
| e-b | 3 |
| e-c | 4 |
| e-d | 5 |

I want to transform the data to below format, and if working with 2 dictionaries, ensure that the two dictionaries have the same keys so that they can be presented side by side on csv(last picture), and compute difference.

| Key | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| e | 3 | 4 | 5 |

[image]

I have no idea how to do this programmatically, (and handle the edge case as well)

My idea thus far:

1. Find col header ('a' in example)
2. Get List from each dictionary containing these col headers.
3. each row will be col header + all values in the List returned from (2)
4. Repeat step 1-3

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I use `DataTable` to parse data from `Dictionary`,you can use the idea and write directly to csv file or improve it:

```cs
Dictionary<string, double> dict = new Dictionary<string, double>();
dict.Add("a-b", 0);
dict.Add("a-c", 1);
dict.Add("a-d", 2);
dict.Add("e-b", 3);
dict.Add("e-c", 4);
dict.Add("e-d", 5);

DataTable data = new DataTable();
data.Columns.Add("Key");

int i = 0;
Dictionary<string, int> indexKey = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var d in dict)
{
    var keys = d.Key.Split('-');
    if (!indexKey.Keys.Contains(keys[0]))
    {
        indexKey[keys[0]] = i++;
        data.Rows.Add(data.NewRow()); 
        data.Rows[indexKey[keys[0]]]["Key"] = keys[0];
    }

    if (!data.Columns.Contains(keys[1]))
        data.Columns.Add(keys[1]);

    data.Rows[indexKey[keys[0]]][keys[1]] = d.Value;
}
```

See the result of the example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LvAQ1o)